# In Sinatra, how to test a route that can return both html and json?

Tags: ruby, json, testing, sinatra, erb

I am still new to Sinatra and I have built my app all based in json, with no views. Now I would like to have the same behaviour but rendering the results on a view. When I was just returning json, my tests all worked. Now I am trying to introduce the erb templates in the routes, and my tests crash, and the variables in the route method don't get passed to the view either.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code of the tests:

**main_spec.rb:**

```
describe "when a player joins the game" do

  it "welcomes the player" do
    post "/join", "data" => '{"name": "Jon"}'
    response = {status: Messages::JOIN_SUCCESS}
    expect_response_to_eq(response)
  end

  it "sends an error message if no name is sent" do
    post "/join", "data" => '{}'
    response = {status: Messages::JOIN_FAILURE}
    expect_response_to_eq(response)
  end

  it "sends an error message if player could not join the game" do
    fill_the_game
    post "/join", "data" => '{"name": "Jon"}'
    response = {status: Messages::JOIN_FAILURE}
    expect_response_to_eq(response)
  end

  it "returns an empty response if no data is sent" do
    post "/join"
    expect_response_to_eq({})
  end

  def expect_response_to_eq(response)
    expect(last_response).to be_ok
    expect(JSON.parse(last_response.body, symbolize_names: true)).to eq(response)
  end

  def fill_the_game
    server.join_game("Jane")
    server.join_game("Joe")
    server.join_game("Moe")
    server.join_game("May")
  end

end
```

where `Messages` is a module that contains string messages for the game.

The controller method I am trying to test initially looked like this, it just returned the response in json format:

**main.rb**

```
post "/join" do
  response = helper.join_response(params)
  @title   = Messages::JOIN_TITLE
  response.to_json
end
```

The helper is a class where I extracted all the business logic so that the controller only has to deal with HTTP requests. I use dependency injection to pass the helper to the main controller, so that it is easier to test.

So up to here, if I run the tests, they are green. But now I want to render the results of the response in the views through erb, while still returning the json. So I added a test like this:

**main_spec.rb:**

```
  it "renders the join page" do
    h = {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}
    post "/join", "data" => '{"name": "Jon"}', "headers" => h
    expect(last_response).to be_ok
    expect(last_response.body).to include(Messages::JOIN_TITLE)
  end
```

And then modified the join router to make the test pass (I'm requiring `sinatra-contrib` for this):

**main.rb:**

```
post "/join", :provides => ['html', 'json'] do
  response  = helper.join_response(params)
  @title    = Messages::JOIN_TITLE
  @r_status = response[:status]

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { erb :join }
    format.json { response.to_json }
  end

  response.to_json
end
```

This broke all my tests with the message:

```
Failure/Error: expect(last_response).to be_ok
       expected `#<Rack::MockResponse:0x007f89e9a941e0...` 
       # ommited this part due to space constrains
       `...@body=["<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>"]>.ok?` to return true, got false
```

So I tried something else:

**main.rb:**

```
post "/join", :provides => ['html', 'json'] do
  response  = helper.join_response(params)
  @title    = Messages::JOIN_TITLE
  @r_status = response[:status]

  request.accept.each do |type|
    case type.to_s
    when 'text/html'
      halt erb :join
    when 'text/json'
      halt response.to_json
    end
  end

end
```

Broke everything as well with a different message:

```
Failure/Error: expect(JSON.parse(last_response.body, symbolize_names: true)).to eq(response)

JSON::ParserError:
  784: unexpected token at '*/*'
```

If I add a line at the end, `response.to_json`, just before closing the method, my tests pass except for the last line of the test for the view,  `expect(last_response.body).to include(Messages::JOIN_TITLE)`. Indeed when I load the page in a browser,  the `@title` seems to be sent to the page but not the `@r_status` for some reason. In the erb view, I have `<p><%= @r_status %></p>`, so it should show up. The title is rendered in the layout erb, as `<h1><%= @title %></h1>`.

I have printed the value of `@r_status` and it is correct, but if I print stuff from inside the `when` blocks, it's like it never hits those.

What is it that I am doing wrong?
Why is the @r_status not rendered in the view and why aren't the `when` blocks hit? How can I make the controller return both html or json and most importantly, how can I test that?

### Update:

I have updated the first test to send the specific headers:

```
it "welcomes the player" do
  h = {"Content-Type" => "application/json", "Accept" => "application/json"}
  post "/join", "data" => '{"name": "Jon"}', "headers" => h
  response = {status: Messages::JOIN_SUCCESS}
  expect_response_to_eq(response)
end
```

And the I run just that test

```
$ rspec spec/main_spec.rb:20
```

When I print the request info from the controller, this is what I get:

```
p request.content_type
application/x-www-form-urlencoded

p request.accept
[#<Sinatra::Request::AcceptEntry:0x007f86de1566b8 @entry="*/*", @type="*/*", @params={}, @q=1.0>]

p params
{"data"=>"{\"name\": \"Jon\"}", "headers"=>{"Content-Type"=>"application/json", "Accept"=>"application/json"}}
```

Seems like it is not taking my headers... so when I do `request.accept.each do |type| case type.to_s` it returns `*/*` which doesn't match neither html nor json, and that's why it never run the code inside the `when` statements. Should I manually redirect to erb or json in the route method using my params? How can I do that?

Comment: Can you provide the error backtrace when you run the specs?

Comment: @Kashyap Sorry my bad. I have updated the question with the error messages I got.

Comment: The first test failure you're seeing is because the server encountered a 500 Internal error, and is unable to send back any of the expected data. Can you check the logs and see what happened? Second error seems to be some issue with JSON parsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. The problem was in the headers as I suspected. I was not sending them correctly.

According to [the docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/testing.html#racktests-mock-request-methods), this is the signature of the HTTP methods when used in tests:

```
get '/path', params={}, rack_env={}
```

So my test didn't work, because the third argument is [a rack environment variable](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/file/SPEC) and I was passing the headers there:

```
h = {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}
post "/join", "data" => '{"name": "Jon"}', "headers" => h
```

Instead, I have to add each header separately calling `header(header_name, header_value)` before calling the method. So now my JSON tests look like this:

```
  it "welcomes the player" do
    header "Accept", "application/json"
    post "/join", {"name" => "Jon"}
    response = {status: Messages::JOIN_SUCCESS}
    expect_response_to_eq(response)
  end
```

and my view tests look like this:

```
  it "renders the join page" do
    header "Accept", "text/html"
    post "/join", {"name" => "Jon"}
    expect(last_response).to be_ok
    expect(last_response.body).to include(Messages::JOIN_TITLE)
  end
```

And my production code in **main.rb** works:

```
  post "/join", :provides => ['html', 'json'] do
    response  = helper.join_response(params)
    @title    = Messages::JOIN_TITLE
    @r_status = response[:status]

    request.accept.each do |type|
      case type.to_s
      when 'text/html'
        halt erb :join
      when 'application/json'
        halt response.to_json
      end
    end
    error 406
  end
```

If I print the headers I get:

```
p headers  
{"Content-Type"=>"application/json"}        # for JSON
{"Content-Type"=>"text/html;charset=utf-8"} # for the views
{"Content-Type"=>"text/html;charset=utf-8"} # in the browser
```

And if I print them from the request, I get:

```
p request.accept
# for JSON:
[#<Sinatra::Request::AcceptEntry:0x007fcf973ff480 @entry="application/json", @type="application/json", @params={}, @q=1.0>]
# for the views:
[#<Sinatra::Request::AcceptEntry:0x007f5791fe29d8 @entry="text/html", @type="text/html", @params={}, @q=1.0>]
# in the browser:
<Sinatra::Request::AcceptEntry:0x007f2fd5a0ee50 @entry="text/html", @type="text/html", @params={}, @q=1.0>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first test failure is because of an error that's happening in the application, so you need to check the logs to see what's triggering it. (Are you loading Sinatra-Contrib's RespondWith module since `respond_to` is not a method provided by Sinatra).

The second example's error is because of mismatch of header expectations between the test and the application. In the app, you're using `request.accept.each` which iterates over the `Accept` headers that the request sent to your app, which by default is '*/*', but the test sends the header of `Content-Type` which won't trigger the conditional case statement.

Comment: Yes, I am requiring the `sinatra-contrib` gem. For the second error I have tried with `request.content_type.each` as well. I have updated my question at the bottom.